# Sqlalchemy core - dynamic SQL query and escaping values

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I’m creating a dynamic Insert query.

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO `" + self.db_name + "` ("
    sql += ','.join(e.db_name for e in self.fields)
    sql += ") VALUES ("
    sql += ','.join(("'" + e.value + "'") for e in self.fields)
    sql += ");"
    result = s.execute(sql)
```

It works fine, except the inserted value is not safe of special characters and SQL injection.

I cant use the SqlAlchemy *text()* mechanism because i don’t know the names or quantity of fields in table.

I tryed *MySQLdb.escape_string()*, but its not working with Unicode.

How can i make a dynamic sql Insert query while escaping special characters in unicode value?

Comment: This is *wrong* approach if you indent to use SQLAlchemy. Do you have SQLAlchemy model classes? You can use them dynamically. If you don't you can also generate SQLAlchemy models in-fly: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/automap.html

Comment: You'd possibly use `table()` and `column()`, the light weight analogues of `Table` and `Column`, but this reeks of an XY problem. Why would one not know the names of their tables etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I wanted to hear 4 years ago -

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO some_table (guid, name) VALUES (:guid_val, :name_val)'

db_session.execute(sql, {
  "guid_val": uuid.uuid4(),
  "name_val": "Hello world"
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is the correct approach? Is this like prepared statements for Sqlalchemy? Is this the same as 

    values = {"guid_val": uuid.uuid4(), "name_val": "Hello World"}
    sql = some_table.insert()    
    sql.insert({**values})

using sqlalchemy core?

Comment: If you want to make simple INSERT - using sql.insert() is better then my answer. My question 4 years ago was about constructing safe custom queries with many unknowns. The main problem is SQL injection. Using parameterized execution is far safer than just constructing a SQL string with values and executing it.